# Laravel - parameters in filter and routes

Tags: php, laravel-4, filter, laravel-routing

I have the following code:

filters.php

```
Route::filter('empty_cart', function () {
    if (empty(Cart::contents()) || Cart::totalItems() == 0) {
        return Redirect::to('');
    }
});
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf','before' => 'detectLang','before' => 'empty_cart'), function () {
    Route::get('site/{slug}/cart', array('uses' => 'CartController@getCart'));
    Route::get('site/{slug}/cart/billing', array('uses' => 'CartController@getBilling'));
    Route::get('site/{slug}/login', array('uses' => 'UsersController@getLoginForm'));
});
```

How can I redirect the user to the `"site/{$slug}"` if the cart is empty? Can I use parameters in the filter.php or how can I send the "slug" to the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is likely in your `Route::group` line. You are passing an array of filters to run but giving each individual item the same key. You should split each before filter with a pipe `|`:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf|detectLang|empty_cart'), function () {
    // Your routes here
}
```

The routes you define within the group will only be valid when all 3 filters are passed, if any of the filters fail, you will get a 404. If you would like to implement certain action when a filter fails you can remove this filter in the routes file and implement it on the controller's constructor or elsewhere.

Alternatively, you could try adding another route **after** this group, that doesn't apply the filters such that any requests that don't match the filtered routes will be caught by this event. You could then put your redirect in place.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf|detectLang|empty_cart'), function () {
    Route::get('site/{slug}/cart', array('uses' => 'CartController@getCart'));
}

Route::get('site/{slug}/cart', 'YourController@yourAction');
// OR
Route::get('site/{slug}/cart', function($slug){
    return Redirect::to('/'. $slug);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed that already but that was not the issues! This worked fine. The Problem is, how to ge tthe slug parameter from the route to the filter.

Comment: How is it possible to do that: "If you would like to implement certain action when a filter fails you can remove this filter in the routes file and implement it on the controller's constructor or elsewhere." ?

Comment: You would simply remove the `empty_cart` filter for example and in your `CartController->__construct()` method, put your logic to determine whether or not you should redirect the user, create a 404, or whatever. That way, the filter is not applied in the route file and your controller handles how it should behave when a cart is empty or not empty

Comment: Personally, I think the second option would be the easiest for you to implement. Simply add a new `Route` after your `Route::group` to redirect the user. That way, if `empty_cart` and the other 2 filters pass, `CartController@getCart` is called, if any of them fail, then your redirect is performed